# How to create a derived class with same default constructor but with different value?

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope

I have a class like this:

```
//class1.h

class Foo
{
private:
  int m_Value;
public:
  int Foo();
}

//class1.cpp

#include "class1.h"
#define CONST_VARIABLE 12

Foo::Foo()
{
  m_Value = CONST_VARIABLE;
}
```

and a derived class:

```
//class2.h

#include "class1.h"

class Foo2 : public Foo
{
puplic:
  Foo2();
  //other functions here
}

//class2.cpp

#define CONST_VARIABLE 24;
#include "class2.h"

Foo2::Foo2() : Foo()
{
}
```

However, when I called

```
Foo a;
Foo2 b;
```

Those 2 (`a` and `b`) have the same `m_Value` (which is 12).

I knew `Foo2()` will call `Foo()` first so `m_Value` will take the `CONST_VARIABLE` in class `Foo`. Thus, I try re-define it but with no luck.

Since both classes are initialized the same way but with different default values and I can't add parameter to the default constructor.

How can I create a derived class with same default constructor but with different value? And in the long run, I could easily maintain or modify the code by changing the the value quickly.

Comment: you can add `m_Value = CONST_VARIABLE;` to the Foo2 constructor.

Comment: Thanks. However, that would assign m_Value twice. Is there anyway I could reduce it to once.
Those code above was just an example, in my real code, `a` is a 2-D array, so it will cost a lot if I re-assign it. Any luck?

Comment: You're not going to pull this off with the preprocessor. You may as well remove `CONST_VARIABLE` and just put `12` and `24` in the respective assignments in your code. What you're attempting is not how the preprocessor works, and frankly the idea of wanting something the "same" but "different" should be a pungent hint of a design problem. If you want a different value, it must be pushed through either by default-value construction parameter or by a template via traits argument of some sort. Trying to wrench a solution with the preprocessor is *not* a sound solution (as you've seen).

Comment: `int Foo();` doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `protected` constructor so that only derived classes can use the constructor specifying a different member value:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
protected:
    explicit Foo(int value);
private:
    int m_Value;
};

Foo::Foo() :
    m_Value(12)
{}

Foo::Foo(int value) :
    m_Value(value)
{}

class Foo2 {
public:
    Foo2();
};

Foo2::Foo2 :
    Foo(24)
{}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could make `m_Value` protected, and modify it in the `Foo2` constructor: `Foo2::Foo2() : Foo() { m_Value = 24; }`.  I concede that this isn't necessarily optimal, but it's easier to maintain for base classes with many such members than maintaining a myriad of constructors for them, and writing a bunch of shim functions to compute the values to pass to them entirely in the member initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Adhering to your requirement that there is only a default constructor, you can accomplish that with a template. Assuming you have full control over your implementation:

```
template <int CONST_VALUE>
class FooT {
protected:
    int m_Value;
    FooT () : m_Value(CONST_VALUE) {}
};

class Foo : FooT<12> {
    //...
};

class Foo2 : FooT<24> {
    //...
};
```

If `Foo2` must inherit from `Foo` directly, you can move the parts that need to be initialized into a super parent class, and then use virtual inheritance of it by `Foo` so that `Foo2` can initialize the super parent directly. This avoids needing to implement two constructors in `Foo` (one default one, and one to let `Foo2` dictate initialization).

```
class FooBase {
protected:
    int m_Value;
    FooBase (int v) : m_Value(v) {}
};

class Foo : public virtual FooBase {
public:
    Foo () : FooBase(12) {}
    //...
};

class Foo2 : public Foo {
public:
    Foo2 () : FooBase(24) {}
    //...
};
```